# Blur background of text field (tailwind or plain css)

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, tailwind-css, blur

I want a text to have a blured white background. But im actually struggling with the blur effect. Everytime i try to use filter blur, the div gets blured but my text disappears.

Here is my code so far written with tailwindcss:

```
<div class="inline-block">
          <div class="px-1 filter blur bg-white bg-opacity-75">
            <span
              class="font-bold text-black-dark text-sm leading-17px z-1003"
            >
              {{ dynamicText }}
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
```

And here is what it should look like:

[image]

Because the text is dynamic, i cant set a fixed width or height to my parent div element. Can anybody help me to achieve a result as desired above?

Answer (score 6):

You can try `backdrop-filter: blur(10px);`

As explained here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backdrop-filter/

Latest Tailwind (v2.1.0) does have it backed in: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/releases#new-filter-and-backdrop-filter-utilities

So, a `backdrop-filter backdrop-blur` should be enough if you're up to date.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this aint working for me. The effect is not the desired and backdrop-filter/blur is not supported by firefox.. :(

Comment: Did you tried the alternatives shown on CSS tricks in the given link ?

Comment: Hi @kissu, yes i tried it. Not the desired effect and also not supported by firefox :(

The effect should be some kind of "cloud effect". Think this is the better naming instead a blur...

Comment: Did you looked up on codepen for a similar effect to what you're looking for ? https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=smoke+text&page=1&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false

Comment: yeah i already looked there but didnt find any similar :(

Comment: Hard to help on a CSS effect if we don't know how it looks. :/

Comment: Oh sorry, didnt know it was unclear. Seeing the appended image in my first post with the "Operations" example, i have a screen wide picture in my background. And over this picture i have some names (e.g. Operations). To highlight this name from the big background picture, there is some kind of blurry effect (in my design proposal it is a white background behind the text with some padding and blurred).

Answer (score -2):

From your screenshot, it looks like you want an outer glow. Try this something like this!

```
text-shadow: 0 0 32px black;
```

The first values are the `x` and the `y`. The third value is the shadow blur value and the last is, well, the color.

Comment: Thanks but this does not work and is not what im looking for